# How to fetch the values from two DE's and insert into another DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, cloudpage, content-builder

I'm trying to track the landing pages opens/clicks data into a Data Extension. I'm fetching the CHILD BU details and LANDING PAGE details through two DE's (here I'm storing and fetching the data )and inserting into a DE along with the subscriber key and JOB ID.

** Code in the Email **

```
%%[ SET @Sub = _subscriberkey SET @CloudPageID = 1234]%%
```

** Code in the Landing Page **

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>My Landing Page</title>


%%[ 

set @Subs = AttributeValue('_SubscriberKey')
 set @JobId = AttributeValue('jobID')
 set @memberid = AttributeValue("memberid")
 set @pageURL = RequestParameter("PAGEURL")


 Set @lookUp = LookupRows('Page Visits','Subscriber Key', @Subs,'jobid', @jobid)
 SET @variableA  = LookupRows('BU Details','memberid', @memberid)

 SET @variableB  = LookupRows('Landing Page Details','CPID',@CPID)

IF Rowcount(@variableA) >0 THEN
   SET @BURow = Row(@lookupvalue, 1)
   Set @BUName = Field(@BURow, 'BUName')
ENDIF 

IF Rowcount(@variableB) >0 THEN
   SET @CPRow = Row(@lookupvalue1, 1)
   Set @CPNAME = Field(@CPRow, 'CPNAME')
ENDIF 


 IF RowCount(@lookUp) == 0 THEN 
 InsertData('Page Visits','Subscriber Key', @Subs,'jobid', @jobid,'memberid', @memberid, 'BUName', @BUName , 'pageURL', @pageURL,'CPNAME', @CPNAME,'Event Date', NOW())
ENDIF 
 ]%%

</head>
<body>

<h1>We are tracking your landing page!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [CloudPagesURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) in the email to the landing page to pass the parameters to the CloudPage.

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(1234))=%%" alias="Link">Link to landing page</a>
```

CloudPagesURL will pass the `_subscriberkey`, `jobID`, and `memberid` used in your `AttributeValue` function.

Comment: If we use memberid, it is fetching only the Parent BU name not the Child BU Name. So I Stored all the BU names in a DE and fetching from there. Now I want to fetch the landing page names in the same format (Storing and Fetching from a DE). I'm confused here, how to fetch the data from two DE's?  For fetching BU details code is below Set lookUp = LookupRows('Page Visits','Subscriber Key', Subs,'jobid', jobid)

SET lookupvalue = LookupRows('BU Details','memberid', memberid)


IF Rowcount(lookupvalue) >0 THEN
   SET BURow = Row(lookupvalue, 1)
   Set BUName = Field(BURow, 'BUName')
ENDIF

Comment: Is the landing page on the Parent BU and you're trying to retrieve from a Child BU?

Comment: No,Landing page is in Child BU and trying to retrieve from a Child BU only. And using memberid from child BU retrives only Parent BU name.

Comment: Try using the v function to see if the variables are being populated. For example, %%=v(@memberid)=%%. Your lookup may not be working if those parameters are not passed. Which is why I put the solution as to use CloudPagesURL